# Convert UIImage (containing PNG Image) to NSData, pixels whose alpha = 0 lose their RGB value

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, pixel, alpha

So I have a UIImage containing a PNG Image.  If I convert that Image to NSData, then convert it back to UIImage, the image is fine BUT any pixel who's alpha was 0 loses it's RGB value.  They become zero... Why is that?  Is there anyway I can retain them?

Here's a code segment:

```
// Declare a new NSData
NSData test = new NSData();
// Convert my Image (PNG) to NSData
test = MyImageView.Image.AsPNG();
// Convert the NSData back to UIImage
UIImage workAroundImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(test);
MyImageView.Image = workAroundImage;
```

Now if I were to check the pixels I'd see that any pixel who's  Alpha value was 0 has 0,0,0 for RGB values as opposed to the original values!  Why is this?

Here is a dropbox link to an example showing this.  Run this project, an image will get some pixel's alpha zeroed out.  The RGB values will remain intact.  You can uncomment the print statements to see this.  Then if you tap on the screen (See TouchesBegan function)  It converts the UIImage to NSData, then back to UIImage.  Then it prints all the pixel data to the screen again.  Here you will see all 0,0,0,0 for the RGBA data showing that any instance where Alpha was zeroed it did not retain RGB values.  Why is this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/21d5k1yex475u2j/TestAlpha_WorkaroundIssue.zip

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that?

That sounds like a conversion to premultiplied alpha was done on the image data. That *killed* every RGB values (by multiplying them with 0).

> Is there anyway I can retain them?

Sadly doing the reverse operation is not possible. You need to keep the original image/values.